# ASP.NET MVC: can a controller call another controller and tell it to delete data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Datasets model class like this:

```
public class Datasets
{
    public Datasets()
    {
        if (id == null)
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    [Key]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

For that model class, I have a `Delete.cshtml` page which allows the user to delete the dataset from the page and thus the database:

```
<form asp-action="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

DatasetsController.cs

```
// GET: Datasets/Delete/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var datasets = await _context.Datasets
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.id == id);

    if (datasets == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(datasets);
}

// POST: Datasets/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    var datasets = await _context.Datasets.FindAsync(id);
    _context.Datasets.Remove(datasets);            
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

The unique `id` is also found in other tables in the database. I wish to delete all the rows in the table that match the same `id`.

Other controllers have a key called:

```
public string dataset { get; set; }
```

How do I notify the other controllers from the `DatasetsController` that they need to delete the corresponding data that matches the `id` (if id == dataset, then delete).

Can I call a specific controller from another controller? I have 5 other controllers that would need to be notified of the delete data call.

I have a tried the following but it did nothing

```
RedirectToAction("ATSController", "Delete", new { Delete = id });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Other Controllers are not initialized and when you redirect to them they will not have dataset value initialized. You should create a service class which will do deletion from all the tables and you call the service class' delete method from the controller. Calling one controller from another is not a good idea and it will not work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In an MVC application there is or there should be a separation between UI stuff, represented by controllers and the business logic which is where stuff happens.

One way to build an MVC application is to keep the controllers very thin, in other words controllers do the model validation then call let's say a service method which does what needs done and then it returns the result.

If you organise things this way then you will not have to call a controller from another controller, you work with services and you can continue to separate your business logic by creating multiple services each targeting  a specific area of your business logic.
That makes it then possible to unit test the  logic without worrying about controllers at all.

You then build services based on interfaces, so each service would have an interface which describes what it does, this is its contract.
The final piece is that you inject whatever services you need in whatever controller needs that service, via dependency injection which is very well supported by the MVC framework.

This would give you a solid foundation to build your app on.